# gocolly: How to Prevent duplicate crawling, restrict to unique url crawling ONCE

Tags: go, web-scraping, go-colly

I was experimenting with go-colly with below code, it seems to crawl same url multiple times, how do I restrict to one time crawling?

I suspected the 'Parallellsim:2' was causing the duplicates, however, some of the crawl message urls repeated more than 10 times each.

Reproducible across different websites.

gocolly is lean and great.

[image]

```golang
func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains( "www.coursera.org"),
        colly.Async(true),
    )

    c.Limit(&colly.LimitRule{
        DomainGlob: "*",
         Parallelism: 2,
    })

    c.OnHTML("a[href]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        link := e.Attr("href")
        e.Request.Visit(link)
    })
    pageCount :=0
    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        r.Ctx.Put("url", r.URL.String())
    })

    // Set error handler
    c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
        log.Println("Request URL:", r.Request.URL, "failed with response:", r, "\nError:", err)
    })

    // Print the response
    c.OnResponse(func(r *colly.Response) {
        pageCount++
        urlVisited := r.Ctx.Get("url")
        log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%d  DONE Visiting : %s", pageCount, urlVisited))
    })

    baseUrl := "https://www.coursera.org"
    c.Visit(baseUrl)
    c.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Ctx` is shared between requests if you use `e.Request.Visit(link)`, so other requests may overwrite the data. Try to use `c.Visit()` in these situations. It creates new context for every request.

Also, you don't need to store the URL in the context, it is always available in the `OnResponse` callback using `r.Request.URL`.

Change your log messasge to the following to be able to see the real request url:

```golang
log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%d  DONE Visiting : %s", pageCount, r.Request.URL))
```